# combobox jquery com cakephp 2x

Tags: jquery, cakephp

Com o codigo semelhante ao que o jquery ui disponibilza, estou testando esse combobox no meu cakephp, o problema é que de maneira alguma ele mostra a setinha para habilitar o dropdown do menu, já baixeio jquery ui com a pasta das imagens, e ainda não funcionou. Código abaixo:

o código inteiro no meu cakephp está assim:

```
<?php $this->start('script'); ?>
<script src="/js/jquery.currency.js"></script>
 <script>
        var current = new Date();
        var aux = new Date(current.getFullYear(), current.getMonth(), current.getDate() + 7);
        if (aux.getDay() != 1) {
var nextMonth = new Date(aux.getFullYear(), aux.getMonth() + 1, 1);
        var days = Math.floor((nextMonth - aux) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))

        if (days < 7)
        current = new Date(aux.getFullYear(), aux.getMonth(), aux.getDate() + days);
        else
        current = aux;
} else {
current = aux;
}
$("#data-inicio").datepicker({
minDate: current,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado', 'Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        return [date.getDay() == 1, ""]
        },
});       
 </script>
    <?php $this->end(); ?>
     <?php $this->start('script'); ?>
     <script>
  (function( $ ) {
$.widget( "custom.combobox", {
  _create: function() {
    this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
      .insertAfter( this.element );

    this.element.hide();
    this._createAutocomplete();
    this._createShowAllButton();
  },

  _createAutocomplete: function() {
    var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
      value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

    this.input = $( "<input>" )
      .appendTo( this.wrapper )
      .val( value )
      .attr( "title", "" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
      .autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
      })
      .tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
      });

    this._on( this.input, {
      autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.item.option.selected = true;
        this._trigger( "select", event, {
          item: ui.item.option
        });
      },

      autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
    });
  },

  _createShowAllButton: function() {
    var input = this.input,
      wasOpen = false;

    $( "<a>" )
      .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
      .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
      .attr("role","button")
      .tooltip()
      .appendTo( this.wrapper )
      .button({
        icons: {
          primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
        },
        text: false
      })
      .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
      .addClass( "ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
      .mousedown(function() {
        wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
      })
      .click(function() {
        input.focus();

        // Close if already visible
        if ( wasOpen ) {
          return;
        }

        // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
        input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
      });
  },

  _source: function( request, response ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
    response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
      var text = $( this ).text();
      if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
        return {
          label: text,
          value: text,
          option: this
        };
    }) );
  },

  _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

    // Selected an item, nothing to do
    if ( ui.item ) {
      return;
    }

    // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
    var value = this.input.val(),
      valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
      valid = false;
    this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
      if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
        this.selected = valid = true;
        return false;
      }
    });

    // Found a match, nothing to do
    if ( valid ) {
      return;
    }

    // Remove invalid value
    this.input
      .val( "" )
      .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
      .tooltip( "open" );
    this.element.val( "" );
    this._delay(function() {
      this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
    }, 2500 );
    this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
  },

  _destroy: function() {
    this.wrapper.remove();
    this.element.show();
  }
});
 })( jQuery );
 $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
 $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {$( "#combobox" ).toggle();});

</script>
<?php $this->end(); ?>
 <?php
 $this->TipoCurso = ClassRegistry::init('TipoCurso');
$this->Idioma = ClassRegistry::init('Idioma');
$this->Localidade = ClassRegistry::init('Localidade');
  $listaCurso = $this->TipoCurso->find('list');
 $listaIdioma =         $this->Idioma->find('list',array('conditions'=>array('ativo'=>1),'order'=>'id'));
 $listaLocalidade = $this->Localidade->find('list',array('conditions'=>array('Localidade.localidade_id is null')));
   $opcoesPaisCidade = array();
 foreach($listaLocalidade as $p_id => $p_nome){
   $cidades =    $this->Localidade->find('list',array('conditions'=>"Localidade.Localidade_id ={$p_id}", 'Localidade.programas is not null'));    
$opcoesPaisCidade[$p_id] = $p_nome;

foreach($cidades as $c_id => $c_nome){
    $opcoesPaisCidade[$c_id] = ' - '.$c_nome;
    //die(print_r($opcoesPaisCidade));
}
}
   //die(print_r($opcoesPaisCidade));
 ?>
  <section class="custom-budget-section custom-budget-section-lg">
<div class="shadow">
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <?=
    $this->Form->create('orcamento', array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'Simulador', 'action' => 'index'),
   'type' => 'POST'
 ));
  ?>
        <h2 class="custom-budget-section-title f-white text-center f-light">
            Faça o seu Orçamento personalizado                
        </h2>

        <h3 class="f-transparent-white text-center f-light">
            A forma mais fácil de escolher o intercâmbio ideal para    você.<br/>(Faça uma simulação e veja uma estimativa de custo)
        </h3>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group form-group-white">
                    <label for="">Data de nascimento</label>
                    <?= $this->Form->input('data_nascimento', array('class' => 'form-control mask_date', 'label' => false)) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-group-white">
                    <label for="">País ou cidade</label>                        
                    <div class="ui-widget">                            
                        <select id="combobox" name="data[orcamento][localidade_id]">
                          <option value="">Select one...</option>
                          <?php
                            foreach($opcoesPaisCidade as $p_id => $p_nome){
                          ?>
                          <option value="<?=$p_id?>"><?=$p_nome?></option>
                          <?}?>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-group-white">
                    <label for="">Data de Início</label>
                    <input type="text" name="data[orcamento][data_inicio]" id="data-inicio" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Data de início" aria-describedby="data-inicio-addon">                        
                    <!--label for="tags">Tags: </label>
                    <input id="tags" class='form-control'-->
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group form-group-white">
                    <label for="">Tipo de Curso</label>
                    <?= $this->Form->input('tipoCurso', array('label' => false, 'options' => $listaCurso, 'empty' => 'Selecione um tipo de curso', 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-group-white custom-budget-s-in">
                    <label for="">Duração (semanas)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*Gênero*</label>
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-xs-6">
  <?= $this->Form->input('duracao', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeHolder' => 'Quantidade', 'label' => false)) ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <?= $this->Form->input('sexo', array('class' => 'form-control', 'empty' => 'Selecione', 'label' => false, 'options' => array('M' => 'Masculino', 'F' => 'Feminino'))) ?>                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group form-group-white">
                    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 budget-contact text-center">
                <p>Você pode entrar em <a href="/conteudo/112">contato</a> conosco</p>
            </div>
        </div>
  <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
    </div>        
</div>
```

```
 <?=$this->element('/aereo/orcamenton')?>
```

E o meu input aparece assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A setinha não apareçe? Veja no log se está reclamando de imagens.

Comment: Ao contrário, eu estou usando combobox com autocomplete, só que a setinha do dropdown não está aparecendo de jeito nenhum

Comment: Provavelmente você não colocou as imagens no lugar corretor, verifique no log que irá encontrar o erro. dê um f12 e vai em console.

Comment: aparece isso `TypeError: e[b] is not a function`

Comment: Se você usar o Cdn do Jquery-Ui irá ver que funciona normal. Aqui tem o CSS e o JS. https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery-ui

Comment: coloquei a imagem na pergunta de como está aparecendo o input pra mim.